# Sql Server 2008: How to order column with null values to show up in the end

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently not able to sort the column to show up null values in the end

```
SELECT firstPart,secondPart  FROM Exhibit_table d, ExhibitType a WHERE d.case_id ='13-05'
AND d.ExhibitTypeId = TypeId AND d.ComplianceNo = '0' and active = 1 order by             CONVERT(INT, firstPart), secondPart
```

I have 2 columns firstpart and secondpart I need to sort it such a way that it shows in the following order

```
10
11
12 A
12 B
12 C
null null
null null
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a third sorting condition:

```
SELECT firstPart,secondPart 
FROM Exhibit_table d, ExhibitType a 
WHERE d.case_id ='13-05' AND d.ExhibitTypeId = TypeId AND d.ComplianceNo = '0' and active = 1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN firstPart IS NULL AND secondPart IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
CONVERT(INT, firstPart), secondPart
```

This will introduce a calculated field with value of 0 when both fields are NULL and value of 1 otherwise - and sort by that field. You can adjust that condition as needed.

Comment: changing the code to below worked thanks a lot                 SELECT firstPart,secondPart 
FROM Exhibit_table d, ExhibitType a 
WHERE d.case_id ='13-05' AND d.ExhibitTypeId = TypeId AND d.ComplianceNo = '0' and active = 1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN firstPart IS NULL AND secondPart IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
CONVERT(INT, firstPart), secondPart

Comment: By using a case in the order by clause you can get performance issue due to a sort operator in the execution plan. If the column you want to sort by is part of an index, you may avoid the sort, but not if you use a case or function ín the order by clause.